# angular-l10n vs ngx-translate pros and cons

Tags: angular, localization, angular5, ngx-translate

Did anyone tried to check what is the advantages/disadvantages of angular-l10n over ngx-translate?

All i could find is angular-l10n can support localize currency, numbers and dates of your app by adding language code, country code, currency code, timezone.

Someone please tell me why we need to go for angular-l10n over ngx-translate?